# Sonarcube is not covering code for the main

Tags: java, junit, sonarqube, code-coverage, program-entry-point

Hi my code coverage tool is sonar. I have simple main method like this :-

```
public class MAIN {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\software\\winutils");

        //args[0]:- location of the input file args[1]:- ingest date args[2]:- source
        //args[3]:-location of the output file args[4]:-location of the Error file
        //args[5]:-Type of the input file args[6]:-Type of the output file
        String input = args[0];
        String ingestDate = args[1];
        String source=args[2];
        String output=args[3];
        String error=args[4];
        String inputFileType=args[5];
        String outputType=args[6];
    }

}
```

the test class for this is :-

```
 public class MyTest {

    private String inputFilePath;
    private String inputFileType;
    private String ingestDate;
    private String source;
    private String outputPath;
    private String errorPath;
    public Main driver;

    @Test(expected=IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
    public void testMainIncorrectArgs() throws IOException{
        //String[] args = {inputFilePath, inputFileType, ingestDate, source, outputPath, errorPath};
        driver = new MAIN();
        driver.main(new String[]{inputFilePath, inputFileType, ingestDate, source, outputPath, errorPath});
    }

}
```

when i do the code coverage the sonarcube tool is not including Main class code coverage.
I have tried with **PowerMockito** and **Reflection Api** to call the method but result is same.

Comment: why are you doing this `driver = new MemberEligibilityEtlSparkDriver();` and not `driver = new Main();`

Comment: @piy26 Edited please check

Comment: Can you insert some line which actually executes . . . something like `System.out.println(inputFilePath, inputFileType, ingestDate, source, outputPath, errorPath)`

Comment: 1) Do you know if the unit test in your `MyTest` class is actually being executed?  2) You don't need to instantiate a class to execute a static method .......

Comment: Yes actually locally all test are executing but the code coverage is not happening for static class code

Comment: which code coverage tool are you using ? seems that your code coverage tool is excluding static class code.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correctly, your are using SonarQube for static code analysis and looking for your code covered by tests.

As far as i know SonarQube does not generate the code coverage by itself, but uses external tools that do the work. The most common one is [Jacoco](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/), which also has a maven plugin that you can include in your build. 
The generated coverage report can then be included in you SonarQube analysis.
Right now your code coverage should be at zero, since SonarQube does not do the analysis on its own.

If you need examples or more information, feel free to edit your question.

Comment: the code is covered for all test cases except this file code. As total code coverage is 60% but it is not including that main method code coverage.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. So the Sonar uses jacoco library internally for code coverage. 
In my main method i was declaring the variable  from args :-

```
String input = args[0];
String ingestDate = args[1];
String source=args[2];
String output=args[3];
String error=args[4];
String inputFileType=args[5];
String outputType=args[6];
```

So these code is not include in code coverage as per the jacoco doc. 
finally i modified my code using pojo :-

```
 String input = setInput(args[0]);
    String ingestDate = setInput(args[1]);
    String source    = setInput(args[2]);
    String output    = setInput(args[3]);
    String error     = setInput(args[4]);
    String inputFileType= setInput(args[5]);
    String outputType = setInput(args[6]);
```

Which covered my sonar. :)